# Having trouble using multiple captions in a figure environment (with minipage)

Tags: captions, minipage

I'm new to latex and I'm having trouble using 2 captions for 2 minipage environments in a figure environment. The compile error goes "Package floatrow: Captions lost".

Here is my code:

```
\begin{figure}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figures/pc1-out.png}
        \captionof{figure}{PC1 ping PC2}
        \label{fig-PC1-out}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figures/pc1-respond.png}
        \captionof{figure}{PC2 ping PC1}
        \label{fig-PC1-respond}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

Here are the packages:

```
\documentclass[AutoFakeBold]{ctexart}
\usepackage{ctex}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[subfigure]{tocloft}
\usepackage{hyperref}
```

Could anybody help me with the code?

I'm not a native English speaker, so hopefully, you can understand. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Since you load floatrow, why don't you use it?

Comment: OH! That's it! Thanks a lot! I'm not familiar with latex so I just copy-and-paste code pieces XD. Floatrow should work!

Comment: And you won't have  to use minipages!